# JavaScript- "Image not found" unless I refresh the page

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm developing simple chat app using `node.js` for server and `HTML`,`CSS`,`JavaScript` for the client side , for each registered user I generate a gravatar depending on his email, for anonymous users (with no emails) I set a default user image.I save users' details in an array in the server so when users are logged in they see chat messages and next to them the user image or his gravatar.

The problem is that for real time updates messages are displayed but images are not unless I refresh the page. I'm sure that the the url of the images saved in the server is legal because other wise they cannot be displayed even when refreshing the page.

I get the follwing error :

> GET /client/undefined" Error (404): "Not found"

***EDIT***

server.js:

```
function addMessage(message) {   
    var m = (message); 
    if (m.email === "" || m.email===undefined) {
        gravatar = "/client/images/user.png";
    } else {
        var userimg= globalVar.usersList.findIndex(function (element) {
            return element.email === m.email;
        });
        gravatar=globalVar.usersList[userimg].gravatar;
    }
    var newMessage = {
        name: m.name,
        email: m.email,
        gravatar: gravatar,
        message: m.message,
        timestamp: m.timestamp,
    }
    globalVar.messagesList.push(newMessage);
}



function getMessages(counter) {
        var messages = [];

        messages = globaVar.messagesList.filter(function (element) {
            return element.id > counter;
        });
        return messages;
    }
...//after checking the url 
     var newMessages = getMessages(counterFromClient);
     response.statusCode = 200;
     response.end(JSON.stringify(newMessages));
```

in client :

```
getMessages(window.Babble.msgCounter, function (res) {
            var newMessages = JSON.parse(res), i;
            var chatList = document.getElementsByTagName('ol')[0];
            var listItem, contDiv, imageDiv, userImage, msgDiv, ct, tm, btn, spn;
            for (i = 0; i < newMessages.length ; i++) {
                listItem = document.createElement('li');

                contDiv = document.createElement('div');

                imageDiv = document.createElement('div');
                imageDiv.setAttribute("class", "user-image-div");
                userImage = document.createElement('img');
                userImage.setAttribute("alt", "");
                userImage.setAttribute("class", "user-image");
                userImage.setAttribute("src", newMessages[i].gravatar);
                userImage.setAttribute("style", "background: white; border: solid 1px #d7d7d7;");
                imageDiv.appendChild(userImage);

                msgDiv = document.createElement('div');
                msgDiv.setAttribute("class", "message-on-chatboard");
                msgDiv.setAttribute("tabindex", "0");

                ct = document.createElement('cite');
                ct.setAttribute("class", "username");
                ct.innerHTML = newMessages[i].name;

                tm = document.createElement('time');
                tm.setAttribute("class", "time");
                var date = new Date(newMessages[i].timestamp * 1000);
                var hours = date.getHours();
                var minutes = "0" + date.getMinutes();
                tm.innerHTML = hours + ":" + minutes;

                btn = document.createElement('button');
                btn.setAttribute("class", "close");
                btn.setAttribute("aria-label", "delete message");
                btn.setAttribute("tabindex", 0);
                btn.setAttribute("id", "msg" + newMessages[i].id);

                spn = document.createElement('span');
                spn.setAttribute("class", "message-content");
                //console.log(typeof (newMessages[i].message));
                spn.innerHTML = newMessages[i].message;

                msgDiv.appendChild(ct);
                msgDiv.appendChild(tm);

                contDiv.appendChild(imageDiv);
                contDiv.appendChild(msgDiv);
                //append list Item
                listItem.appendChild(contDiv);
                chatList.appendChild(listItem);

            }

function  getMessages(msgCounter, callback) {

        var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (httpRequest.readyState === 4) { // request is done
                if (httpRequest.status === 200) { // successfully
                    //console.log(httpRequest.responseText);
                    callback(httpRequest.responseText); // we're calling our method
                }
            }
        };
        httpRequest.open('GET', "http://localhost:8080/messages?counter=" + msgCounter);
        httpRequest.send();
    }
```

Any idea why this is going and how can I fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: without the code it will be hard to help !

Comment: I'll add code ..

Comment: @sheplu can you help me now ?

Comment: looking your code, and don't know why.
when you have a new message, check inside the html if the src value is right. It's the only thing I see

Comment: It says src="undefined" ..

Comment: so you got your error ! now it will be time to investigate to see if you send the image from your server on update or not

Comment: @sheplu I do send it , because I use the same exact functions also when refreshing ,I use long polling but I don't think this is what causes the problem

Comment: if the same function is  working when you refresh it isn't coming from the function itself. Try to use a `console.log` to displays what is inside your message when you update your chat

Comment: @sheplu you are right ,it prints "undefined" .. I tried Json.stringify but still the same,,but it is undefined only in real time update ,but after refreshing it is as I put the src

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know without the code but seeing the error

```
GET /client/undefined" Error (404): "Not found"
```

It seems that the variable that you used to get the image is not defined (undefined), so verify that first.

Comment: No that is not the problem because I use the same function to display images in all cases, so when refreshing the page I get the images